# Is it possible to set the HSV for a color adjust via css?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have some buttons with simple black images on them. When my program switches to a black theme, I modify the images using a color adjust:

```
private ColorAdjust darkThemeButtons = new ColorAdjust(); {
    darkThemeButtons.setSaturation( -1 );
    darkThemeButtons.setHue( 1 );
    darkThemeButtons.setBrightness( .75 );
}
```

I would *love* to be able to specify these values via CSS and read them into the color adjust rather than specifying them in code. Is that possible?

For example, Is there a way to generically ask a stylesheet for a selector's value? Maybe something like this (psuedocode):

```
HSB color = stylesheet.getSelector( ".darkThemeButtonColor" ).getHSB();
```

Comment: The [CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect) says that the only effects supported are `DropShadow` and `InnerShadow`. (If you were only changing the brightness, you could do something equivalent with the `derive(...)` CSS color function, but you can't change the saturation, etc.)